# How to use material-table and useQuery from Apollo?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, material-table

I use Material-table to display the data of my service and also Appolo client.

When I display my table I have no problem but when I use pagination in the material table, the display remains static.
I am using UseQuery to retrieve my data.

Like this :

The let pageNumber allows to increment

```
let pageNumber = 0;
    const { loading, error ,data } = useQuery(_ALL_COUNTRY_QUERY, {
        variables: { page:  pageNumber+1 },
    });
```

my query matches this:

```
const MASTER_ALL_COUNTRY_QUERY = gql`
    query allCountryWithObject($page : Int) {
        allCountryWithObject(pageable: {size: 30, page: $page}) {
            total
            content {
                name
                continent
            }
        }
    }`;
```

and for the display in the table here is the method I used :

```
return (
        <div className="Grid">
            <div style={{ maxWidth: "100%", paddingTop: "12px" }}>
                <MaterialTable
                    columns={tableColumnConfig}
                    data={query =>
                        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                              resolve({
                                data: data.allCountryWithObject.content.map(o => ({...o})),
                                page: pageNumber+1,
                                totalCount:30
                                });
                        })
                    }
                    title=""
                    icons={{
                        Clear: (props) => <DeleteIcon />,
                        Search: (props) => <SearchIcon />,
                        ResetSearch: (props) => <DeleteIcon />
                    }}
                    />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

I displays 30 values per page and all the data is greater than 100.

unfortunately I only display the first page and when I try to go to the following pages the page does not update.

I saw at Material- table that there was a method of RemoteData but which does not really correspond to the one I want to use with UseQuery

https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/remote-data

If you know a pagination method with useQuery and material-table I would be happy with it ?

Comment: Have you also read the pagination section of the react apollo docs? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/overview/

Comment: @trixn yes but without success !